# grails run-app error Plugin [functional-test-1.2.7] not installed

Tags: grails, run-app

I am using Grails 1.2.1 and Groovy-Grails Tool Suite 3.1.0. Before that I was used 2.5.2.RELEASE of STS. But after upgrading to Groovy-Grails Tool Suite 3.1.0, when I am trying to run the app I am getting the following error:

```
Welcome to Grails 1.2.1 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: C:\Program Files\Grails\grails-1.2.1\

Base Directory: D:\softwares\My_workspace\BluBilling
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 847ms.
Running script C:\Program Files\Grails\grails-1.2.1\scripts\RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
Plugin [functional-test-1.2.7] not installed, resolving..
Reading remote plugin list ...Plugin 'functional-test' was not found in repository. If it is not stored in a configured repository you will need to install it manually. Type 'grails list-plugins' to find out what plugins are available.
```

And when I am open Plugin manager I am getting the empty list but in console window getting one plugin and also getting following error:

```
Welcome to Grails 1.2.1 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: C:\Program Files\Grails\grails-1.2.1\

Base Directory: D:\softwares\My_workspace\BluBilling
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 847ms.
Running script C:\Program Files\Grails\grails-1.2.1\scripts\ListPlugins_.groovy
Environment set to development
Reading remote plugin list ...

Plug-ins available in the core repository are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------

dummy               <0.1 (?)>          --  Plugin summary/headline
hibernate           <1.3.8>          --  Hibernate for Grails
tomcat              <1.3.8>          --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webflow             <1.3.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT> --  Spring Web Flow Plugin
Reading remote plugin list ...

Plug-ins available in the default repository are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------

No plugins found in repository: https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins

Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------

google-chart        0.5.0            --  This plugin adds Google Chart API features to Grails applications.

To find more info about plugin type 'grails plugin-info [NAME]'

To install type 'grails install-plugin [NAME] [VERSION]'

For further info visit http://grails.org/Plugins

Error executing script ListPlugins: grails.util.BuildSettings.getPluginClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: grails.util.BuildSettings.getPluginClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.GrailsBuildSettingsDependencyExtractor.getPluginClassesDir(GrailsBuildSettingsDependencyExtractor.java:63)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.GrailsBuildSettingsDependencyExtractor.getDependencyData(GrailsBuildSettingsDependencyExtractor.java:217)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.GrailsBuildSettingsDependencyExtractor.writeDependencyFile(GrailsBuildSettingsDependencyExtractor.java:201)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.DependencyExtractingBuildListener.receiveGrailsBuildEvent(DependencyExtractingBuildListener.java:79)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure4.doCall(Gant.groovy:324)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure6.doCall(Gant.groovy:334)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure6.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:344)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:334)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:495)
    at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:480)
Error executing script ListPlugins: grails.util.BuildSettings.getPluginClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;
```

I tried to install functional-test plugin using the command:

```
grails install-plugin functional-test
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Welcome to Grails 1.2.1 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: C:\Program Files\Grails\grails-1.2.1\

Base Directory: D:\softwares\My_workspace\BluBilling
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 822ms.
Running script C:\Program Files\Grails\grails-1.2.1\scripts\InstallPlugin.groovy
Environment set to development
Reading remote plugin list ...Plugin 'functional-test' was not found in repository. If it is not stored in a configured repository you will need to install it manually. Type 'grails list-plugins' to find out what plugins are available.
```

Anyone help me please...

Thanks in advance.

Nimmy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your console you can see:

> For further info visit http://grails.org/Plugins

So, you should go to this page and try to find plugin **functional test**. On the page of this plugin [functional test](http://grails.org/plugin/functional-test) you can see

> Dependency :
>
> compile ":functional-test:2.0.RC1"
>
> Custom repositories :
>
> **mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org/"**
>
> **mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/"**

So, try to add this repositories to the BuildConfig.groovy. 
And now current version of grails - 2.2 :)

If it is don't work, try to use last version of plugin: **functional-test:2.0.RC1**